# Difference between full and short command

Tags: command-line

Is there a practical difference between using

```
:e
```

and

```
:edit
```

Except for readability, where it make sense in a mapping to use `:edit`, because it's more explicit.

Is there a difference between them?

*Note:* This apply as well to **all** other commands.

Comment: I consider the short commands as a command line convenience.  I *always* use full command names in scripts.  It's frustrating when the short commands are used in plugins.  It makes grepping/searching scripts harder than it needs to be.

Comment: As @TommyA says.  Consider these excerpts: `setl nobl bt=nofile noswf`, `setl ma ff=unix noro`, `setl ro noma nomod`.  Can you tell quickly what they do?  Look at the `netrw` sources for more inspiration. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no actual difference but in [`:h usr_20.txt`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_20.html#usr_20.txt), you can read:

> It is recommended that in Vim scripts you write the full command name.  That
>   makes it easier to read back when you make later changes.  Except for some
>   often used commands like `:w` (`:write`) and `:r` (`:read`).
>
> A particularly confusing one is `:end`, which could stand for `:endif`,
>   `:endwhile` or `:endfunction`.  Therefore, always use the full name.

So I would recommend to follow the doc and use the long name.

And another paragraph interesting about the short names:

> How short can a command get?  There are 26 letters, and many more commands.
>   For example, `:set` also starts with `:s`, but `:s` doesn't start a `:set`
>   command.  Instead `:set` can be abbreviated to `:se`.
>
> When the shorter form of a command could be used for two commands, it
>   stands for only one of them.  There is no logic behind which one, you have to
>   learn them.  In the help files the shortest form that works is mentioned.

Comment: Also consider `:endfun`.  Who'd want such a thing.

Comment: That would be terrible indeed :-)