# Exclude start and end match from region

Tags: syntax-highlighting

I'm trying to establish syntax coloring for a certain lexical syntax: a "buffer literal". A buffer literal begins with `#b'` and ends with `'`.  Between the single quotes, there can be undivided pairs of hex digits, with optional whitespace in between, that being spaces, tabs and newlines.

Valid buffer literals:

```
#b'' #b'FF' #b'Fe' #b'dead be
                      ef'
```

Invalid:

```
#b'z' #b'FFF'  #b'9 0'
```

Here is what I have:

```
syn match buferr "." contained
syn match bufok "[0-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f]\|[\t\n ]" contained

syn region buflit start="#b'"rs=e+1 end="'"re=s-1 contains=bufok,buferr

hi def link buferr Error
hi def link bufok String
hi def link buflit String
```

The problem is that the `bufok` and `buferr` match items are being applied to the region delimiters. And thus the `#b'` start and `'` end are matching `buferr` and being highlighted as `Error`.

I tried to compensate for this using the `rs` (region start) and `re` (region end) offset options on the `region` patterns, seen above, but it has no effect. The matches are not contained to occur between the indicated region start and end.

How can we tell Vim that we want this:

```
#b'....'
   rrrr  <- this is the region, in which bufok and buferr are contained!
```

It really looks like `rs` and `re` offsets should be doing this, since the documentation says:

> *The pattern can be followed by a character offset.  This can be used to
>   change the highlighted part, and to **change the text area included in the
>   match or region** (which **only matters when trying to match other items**).*

On the contrary, my above fiddling with `rs` and `re` doesn't seem to be having an effect on the matching of contained items.

I'm working with Vim as old as 7.3.429.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a couple of nuances that need to be grasped in order to make it work:

1. The `"."` in `buferr` matches `'` and will eat it up before the pattern in `buflit` can see it and, as a result, the `buflit` region mismatch both delimiters. You could deal with this issue by adding `keepend` (see [`:help :syn-keepend`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/syntax.txt.html#%3asyn%2dkeepend)) before the `conteins` argument, but you won't need it in this case.
2. The `rs` and `re` offsets only make sense when they're used along with `matchgroup`, and that happens to be very helpful because of this (from [`:help :syn-matchgroup`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/syntax.txt.html#%3asyn%2dmatchgroup)):

   ```
   ...
   In a start or end pattern that is highlighted with "matchgroup" the
   contained items of the region are not used.  This can be used to avoid
   that a contained item matches in the start or end pattern match.
   ...
   ```

and, as you'll see below, you won't need the `rs`and `re` offsets in this case either.

```
syntax case ignore
syntax match bufok "\x\x\|\_s" contained
syntax region buferr matchgroup=buflit start="#b'" end="'" contains=bufok

highlight default link buferr Error
highlight default link bufok String
highlight default link buflit String
```

Here the region was redefined by highlighting:

- its content as a error by default
- its delimiters with the `buflit` highlighting group
- the pair of hexadecimal digits with `bufok`

I also:

- made the `:syntax` command case-insensitive with `syntax case ignore` (see :help [`:help :syn-case`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/syntax.txt.html#%3asyn%2dcase)
- used `\x` to match hexadecimal digits (see [`:help /\x`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2f%5cx))
- used `\_s` to match whitespace characters, including the end-of-line (see 
  [`:help /\s`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2f%5cs) and [`:help /\_s`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2f%5c_s))

**Note:** `\x` and `\_s` are faster than the `[]` form.

### Bonus

I used the long form of each command because some experts around here recommend it (and I agree with them), for example:

- From [`:help usr_20.txt`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_20.txt.html#20.2)

  ```
  It is recommended that in Vim scripts you write the full command name.  That
  makes it easier to read back when you make later changes.  Except for some
  often used commands like ":w" (":write") and ":r" (":read").
  A particularly confusing one is ":end", which could stand for ":endif",
  ":endwhile" or ":endfunction".  Therefore, always use the full name.
  ```
- From [romainl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12585831/1121933):

  > you should use the long form names of your settings as they are more readable than their short counterpart. Your future self will thank you.
- From [Tommy A's comment](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/8469/difference-between-full-and-short-command/8470#comment14298_8469):

  > I consider the short commands as a command line convenience. I *always* use full command names in scripts. It's frustrating when the short commands are used in plugins. It makes grepping/searching scripts harder than it needs to be.

Comment: Thanks; this works very well. I already solved the problem by using a single match for buffer literals, but it's not satisfactory because it doesn't pinpoint where the error is in a large buffer literal.

Comment: The use of abbreviations like `syn` and `hi def` is what is used in the official Vim files. I didn't introduce it; it is **copy and paste from the horse's mouth.**  I take whatever is `/usr/share/vim/*/syntax/*` to be the canonical coding style that I should be following for a syntax file (in spite of what the documentation recommends).  **If a syntax file is  ever upstreamed, it should look like other syntax files.**

Comment: Addenum to previous point: in Vim, if you want help for `syntax match` you have to know that it's `:help syn-match`. Not `:help syntax-match`!

Answer (score 3):

Supplementary answer: based on Jair López's clue about `matchgroup`, the following **minimal change** rescues the original concept:

```
syn match buferr "[^']" contained                                                                                                            
syn match bufok "[0-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f]\|[\t\n ]" contained                                                                               

syn region buflit matchgroup=buflit start="#b'" end="'" contains=bufok,buferr                                                  
hi def link bufok String                                                                                                                  
hi def link buferr Error                                                                                                                  
hi def link buflit String
```

The first key difference from the nonworking definition is that there is a `matchgroup=buflit` there which means that the `start` and `end` delimiters are treated as being `bufok`, and colorized as `String` via the `hi def link`.

The second key difference is that the error match is "any character but apostrophe" rather than "any character". This way the error match doesn't compete with the closing delimiter.

Also, the offset specifiers `rs=` and `re=` are removed; they are a red herring in this situation that make no difference.

This solution differs from the accepted solution in a small way: it doesn't require the region to be categorized as a one big `Error` in which the good pieces of syntax are the exceptions to the error. The errors are recognized explicitly within the region as positive matches. The default behavior of "everything else that is not good token material is an error" is implemented by a single character match routed to `Error`: flag and drop the bad character.

The end effect appears identical as far as I can tell with interactive testing.

So the exact differences relative to the accepted solution:

- the region is called `buflit` rather than `buferr` and highlighted as a String.
- the `buferr` name is used for a one character bad `match` rather than the region.
- the region contains `buferr` also, not only `bufok`.

It's good to keep both approaches in mind: error highlights can be identified as explicit matches of erroneous figures on a good background, or as implicitly unmatched gaps between good figures on an error background.