# Using Vim as a syntax highlighting tool - Python and TeX interface

Tags: syntax-highlighting

I am trying to modify Vim's syntax highlighting rules for Python to suit specific needs : in particular, I need to capture all the line after some regexps (`^Out [.*]:` and `^\h\w*Error:`).

After some digging in the vim syntax file python.vim (where I got inspiration from how strings are treated) and [this SE subject](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/13062/exclude-start-and-end-match-from-region), I finally came to this

```
  syntax match OutProc "^Out\s*\[.*\]:"
  syntax match ErrProc "^\h\w*Error:"
  syntax match plainOut ".*" contained
  syntax region PlainOutput matchgroup=plainInit
           \ start="^Out\s*\[.*\]:" end="$" contains=plainOut
  syntax region PlainOutput matchgroup=ErrProc
           \ start="^\h\w*Error:" end="$" contains=plainOut
  highlight default link plainInit OutProc
```

which almost works perfetcly. The only problem is that in the python.vim syntax file, one can find

```
syn keyword pythonExceptions  BaseException Exception
```

and so on for all bult-in exceptions. In consequence, in

```
FooError: int True
TypeError: int True
```

the first line behaves correctly (`int True` is captured in a PlainOutput region) while the second one does not (`TypeError`, `int` and `True` are recognized separately as keywords and hightlihgted as such) : I guess `TypeError` is matched as a keyword instead of the delimiter of the `PlainOutput` region. So finally my question boils down to : how to ensure that the pattern `"^\h\w*Error:"` is recognized as the delimiter instead of a distinct keyword when the keyword already exists ?